# Installation Error Mysql to Debian on BeagleBone

Tags: mysql, terminal

When logging in through `mysql -u root -i`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5`, I've auto removed, cleaned, removed all associated files. After all that, I did a `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*` just to be safe. Then I installed it again: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

I get an error during the installation:

```
Setting up libmysqlclient18:armhf (5.5.43-0+deb7u1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.021-1+b1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.43-0+deb7u1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.43-0+deb7u1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.43-0+deb7u1) ...
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not really sure what else I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess the purge and installation worked. On one last whim, I decided to reboot my BeagleBone and try again. It worked.